# How to use tar to compress a group of files in a .txt file?

Tags: tar

I have a lot of filenames that listed in a .txt file called `to_be_archived_files.txt`, and its content is as:

```
~/Documents/dir1/a.html
~/Documents/dir1/b.html
~/Documents/dir1/c/1.html
```

How do I add all of them into a `archive.tar.gz` by *tar*?

I want something like:

`tar czf archive.tar.gz -FROM-FILELIST=to_be_archived_files.zip`

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `-T` option:

```
 -T, --files-from FILE
       get names to extract or create from FILE
```

Note that it doesn't work with `~` as alias for home directory, you need to specify the folder explicitly.

Comment: awesome. i never tought it was so easy

Answer (score 7):

You'd need to replace that `~` with your home directory first. Assuming your home directory doesn't contain `:` (they generally don't as otherwise they couldn't be referenced in `/etc/passwd`):

```
(cd / &&
  sed "s:^~:$HOME:" | pax -w | gzip) < file.list > file.tar.gz
```

Or if your `tar` is the one from GNU or `bsdtar`:

```
(cd / &&
  sed "s:^~:$HOME:" | tar -T - -zcf -) < file.list > file.tar.gz
```

Some other `tar` have `-I` instead of `-T` for that. `star` uses a `list=-` argument for that (`star cvf - list=-`).

Note that in those solutions above, except for `star`, if any of the files in that list are of type *directory*, then the whole content of those directories is included.

To archive the directory only and not its content, with `pax` add the `-d` option, with GNU `tar` or `bsdtar` the `--no-recursion` one (also `-n` with `bsdtar`).

With `star`, to include the content of the directories, add the `-dodesc` option.

Comment: Hint: You need -dodesc because at the time of introduction if list= (around 1985) list= was used for find | star. Since 10 years, there is a built-in find in star that makes things much easier.